# spring security redirect based on role not working

Tags: java, xml, spring

well i try to redirect user base on role but my custom class do nothing i do some system out but nothing happen.

i follow this small tutorial http://oajamfibia.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/role-based-login-redirect/#comment-12

but i change my extention class for **SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler** i also try the one in the tutorial nothing happen don't know what i missing. Any help will be appreciate.

this is my class

```
@Component
public class RoleBaseAuthentification extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler{

    private Map<String, String> roleMap;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println(request.getUserPrincipal());
        if(authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails){
            UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
            System.out.println(userDetails);
            String role = userDetails.getAuthorities().isEmpty() ? null : userDetails.getAuthorities().toArray()[0].toString();
            System.out.println(role);
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + roleMap.get(role));
        }
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }

    public Map<String, String> getRoleMap() {
        return roleMap;
    }

    public void setRoleMap(Map<String, String> roleMap) {
        this.roleMap = roleMap;
    }


}
```

and here is my security-context.xml

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"> 
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="select username,password,enabled from users where username = ?"
            authorities-by-username-query="select u.username, ur.authority from users u, user_roles ur where u.user_id =  ur.user_id and u.username = ?" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/management" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <security:form-login login-page="/login" authentication-success-handler-ref="redirectByRole"/>
</security:http>

<bean id="redirectByRole" class="com.freelogic.spring.web.service.RoleBaseAuthentification">
<property name="roleMap">
    <map>
        <entry key="ROLE_ADMIN" value="/management.jsp" />
        <entry key="ROLE_USER" value="/home.jsp" />
    </map>
</property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### The problem

Your success handler extends `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` so calling

`super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication)`

causes `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` or one of it's super classes to use their redirect strategies and override yours.

#### The (ergghh) solution

You can prevent the redirect by calling `super.onAuthenticationSuccess()` before your `reponse.sendRedirect()`. It will override the redirecting attempts previously made. While not a good solution it will work. See below why I think it's not a good solution.

#### On a side note

I'm not sure why you are extending `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` and not simply implementing AuthenticationSuccessHandler. The former allows a authenticated user to redirect to it's previous visited page. Your `RoleBaseAuthentification` only redirects by role with no condition to return to a previous url. So your choice to extend `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` does not make sense to me.

Comment: well i recheck the documentation ur right i should just use AuthenticationSuccessHandler i don't need all the other think that SaveRequestAware do. But still not work with both class nothing get call at all.

Comment: Are you sure the correct role is selected from the roleMap? Use a debugger and set a breakpoint on the redirect and look at all the variables of something is off.

Comment: don't know why no error but onAuthenticationSuccess doesn't get invoke at all

Comment: Are you sure the user gets authenticated?

Comment: yeah i can log in out and intercept url for specific role only redirection not working. I decide to forget about the handler and to do it inside my controller and get the auth with SecurityContextHolder and depend which role i redirect to specific page.